# Calculating output forces of bicycle wheels

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Based on the force on the rear gear $F_t$ and the radii of the rear gear $R_g$ and rear wheel $R_w$ , how would you calculate the force the bicycle exerts on the ground when it is accelerating?

I would have thought it would be $$F_t \times (R_g/R_w)$$ but this would mean that the torque of the chain $$F_t\times R_g$$ would equal the torque of static friction $$F_t \times (R_g/R_w)\times R_w = F_t\times R_g$$That obviously cannot be the case if the wheel is angularly accelerating.

So how would you quantify the lag between the two torques?

I have a similar question about the pedal sprocket: how do you calculate the force the pedal sprocket puts on the chain based on the toque on the pedal?

Comment: Lag is not the best word. You just have two different length levers plus gears. I think the torque on the wheel equals the toque on the crank arm.

Comment: "...when it is about to accelerate".  That suggests to me *prior* to acceleration.  But later in the question you talk about acceleration.  Which do you intend?  The answer under acceleration cannot be answered with the information you have.

Comment: I mean while it is accelerating. And why is it that it cannot be answered?

Answer (score 1):

If we take the bicycle as a whole the only force that making the bicycle accelerate is the frictional force applied on the wheels. For the moment lets forget the front wheel. Then, 
$$F_f = Ma$$

Since the wheel is not slipping, for the back wheel 
$$F_t R_g - F_fR_w = I \alpha = I\frac{a}{R_w}$$

With the use of these equations $F_f$ and $a$ can be quatified

Comment: Wouldn't solving it this way give you Ff in terms of acceleration too?

Comment: yes.. but $a$ can be obtained only by $F_t$, $R_g$, $R_w$, $M$ and $I$

Comment: to be precise, $$a= \frac{R_wR_gF_t}{(MR_w^2+I)}$$